# Exercise about pointer to function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an exercise like that. The requirement is to write code in the section

```
#include <iostream>

int minus (int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

void calculate(int a, int b)
{
    int (*myfunc)(int, int);
      
    // STUDENT ANSWER BEGIN


    // STUDENT ANSWER END

    int ans = (*myfunc)(a, b);
    printf("Output of calculation is %d.\n", ans);
}
int main() {
    calculate(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

When I write

```
        int (*myfunc) (int, int) = add;
        int temp = (*myfunc)(a, b);
        cout << temp;
```

the value of *temp* = -1 as expected (just for test) but I can't get the value of *ans*. So, I figure that two *(*myfunc)* is different. How can I fix that?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. When you have `int temp = (*myfunc)(a, b);` the result of the function invocation is saved in the variable `temp`. If you want that value to be associated with `ans`, go with `ans = (*myfunc)(a, b)`?

Comment: Are you possibly just looking for `myfunc = minus;` inbetween `// STUDENT ANSWER BEGIN` and `// STUDENT ANSWER END`? The `myfunc` _function pointer_ has already been _declared_, but not yet _initialized_ (before its usage in the `int ans = (*myfunc)(a, b);` row), in the blueprint for the `calculate` function. In you own example, you are _declaring **and** initializing_ a function pointer `myfunc`.

Comment: When you say that you "can't get the value of ans", what do you mean by that? Can you please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the failing program? What do you expect to happen when you build and run your program? What actually happens? And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you add that code the program won't compile. Did you also remove something outside your designated area in order to fix the compilation error?

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What do you mean "can't get"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
int (*myfunc) (int, int) = add;
```

you are creating a new variable named `myfunc`. If you do it inside the same scope as the original `myfunc`, it is a compilation error, but if you write it inside a new scope (which the indentation of the code you pasted suggest, even if you haven't showed the brackets), you are shadowing the original variable with the new one. By using the name `myfunc` inside that scope, you are referring to the new variable.

The solution is simple. Instead of declaring a new variable, simply assign to the existing one:

```
myfunc = add; // or minus
```

EDIT: I misread the question and interpreted "but I can't get the value of ans" as "but I can't get the value *into* ans". But I'll leave this answer here in case that is what OP meant...

Comment: They should still yield the same output, though, no?

Comment: No, because the original `myfunc` was never assigned.